# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'event'

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating my first game in python and was doing it part by part. Than I got this error message:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'event'
> ```

My code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600

pygame = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_width])

gameover = False

while not gameover:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
```

Comment: don't re-assign pygame. You're blocking the import with the variable you created.

Answer (score 1):

Because the module `pygame` is shadowed by the variable `pygame` that refers to the display *Surface* object. You have to rename the variable that holds the *Surface* object which is associated to the Pygame display:

<s>`pygame = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_width])`</s>

```py
pygame_surf = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_width])
```

Note that when `pygame.event.get()` is called, `pygame` is understood as the *Surface* object `pygame` and a *Surface* object does not have an attribute `event`.